# NGXS - Selecting child state from Parent state

Tags: angular, ngxs

I'm learning NGXS and have a state model with nested parent/child relationships where there are some number of parents that each have their own set of children (and grandchildren), something like this:

```
state: {
    parents: ParentModel[]
}

ParentModel {
    children: ChildModel[]
}

ChildModel {
   grandchildren: GrandChildren[]
}

etc.
```

However, when state is modeled in redux/flux implementations, the above example would (as far as I'm aware) would usually be normalized.

I would like to be able to access children and grandchildren as in a fashion that matches the mental model of the state tree. The best I've come up with is to essentially create a "lazy selector" as described in the docs (https://ngxs.gitbook.io/ngxs/concepts/select#lazy-selectors)

Like this:

```
export class ChildRecordState {
@Selector()
    static childRecords(state: ChildRecordModel) {
        return (id: number) => state.Records.filter(r => r.parentId === id);
    }
// ...
}
```

(Full example without the grandkids here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ngxs-parent-child).

I do see there is Sub State that can be accessed and I can create a selector using that in the parent, but that doesn't really seem to improve the outcome much. The question is - is there a better pattern around accessing children of a parent than shown in the example/stackblitz?

Comment: It seems your StackBlitz example does not link the parent to the child within the store? I.e. if I pull a parent, then the child Records property would just be undefined?